# Access class objects declared with `this` with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a class that looks like:

```
class Dummy {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.dummyObj = 'dummy'
    }
}
```

and I want to access `this.dummyObj` and change its value to say: 'hi'
is this possible with Jest/Enzyme?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by making an instance:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<YourComponent />', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <YourComponent
      {...yourProps}
    />
  );
  const instance = wrapper.instance(); 

  it('Should have correct dummyObj value', () => {
     expect(instance.dummyObj).toBe('dummy');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to mock `dummyObj` value on specific class instance by setting it directly, e.g.:

```
let instance = new Dummy;
instance.dummyObj = 'hi';
```

If the intention is to mock it in other places where `Dummy` is used, and `dummyObj` value is accessed in tested code before an instance could be accessed to be mocked, a good strategy is to mock property descriptor on class prototype and make `dummyObj` read-only:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(Dummy.prototype, 'dummyObj', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: () => 'hi'
  });
});

it('tests the code that instantiates Dummy and uses dummyObj', () => {...});

afterEach(() => {
  delete Dummy.prototype.dummyObj;
});
```

This way `this.dummyObj = 'dummy'` is efficiently ignored on class instantiation.